# How to optimize/avoid switch condition in javascript when seperate function calls are required

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, prototypejs

I ended up with this code a few minutes ago and it left me wondering whether there would be an elegant way to optimize it into fewer lines, with the optional bonus of perhaps avoiding the switch condition.

```
        switch(orientation){
            case 'l':
                $('landscapeButton').addClassName('active');
                $('portraitButton').removeClassName('active');
                break;
            default:
                $('landscapeButton').removeClassName('active');
                $('portraitButton').addClassName('active');
        }
```

Is it possible to further optimize this code? And if yes, how would you accomplish it?

**Edit: I should have included some info on which library/libraries i am using. In fact i use both, but in this example i use prototype, as i prefer to use that for dealing with CSS class names. In any case, in my specific case it didn't matter whether the solution was provided in Prototype or jQuery. Thanks to everyone!**

Comment: You are correct. I apologize to everybody - stupid mistake. Its corrected now.

Comment: If you are using jQuery then addClassName should be addClass and removeClassName should be removeClass.

Comment: could you put some more options for your switch case. For the current case, a if else wont be simpler ?

Comment: Thank You, Shusl - i am using prototype here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*For prototypejs:*

If `orientation` will be `1` or `0`, use a function that takes a switch argument to toggle appropriately.

```
function safeToggleClass(id, clss, switch) {
    return $(id)[(!!switch ? "add" : "remove") + "ClassName"](clss);
}
```

---

```
safeToggleClass('landscapeButton', 'active', +orientation);
safeToggleClass('portraitButton', 'active', !+orientation);
```

---

*For jQuery:*

jQuery has this switch built in to their `toggleClass` method.

```
$('#landscapeButton').toggleClass('active', +orientation);
$('#portraitButton').toggleClass('active', !+orientation);
```

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what i dreamed of! Thank You! Case closed.

Comment: You're welcome. I just gave an update because I noticed you were using strings for `orientation`, so now I'm converting to numbers first. Also, I assume the values are `1` and `0`.

Comment: @CummanderCheckov: Oh wait, you're using `prototypejs`? Sorry, I assumed it was jQuery. I'm not sure if they have this ability. I'll check quick.

Comment: Here's the thing - i was about to implement your code, would have noticed that its jQuery you provided in the end. No biggie, as i include both libraries in my project. I just usually prefer prototype for dealing with CSS classes.

Comment: @CummanderCheckov: I would advise against including both libraries. Give me a minute, and I'll post a solution that will work like this.

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts. Unfortunately, i am so deep into my project and it incorporates too many functions from prototype, so dropping that library is not an option for me. However, i never experienced any issues with combining the libraries as long as i used jQuery's noConflict() solution. PS.: I think you have forgotten to add the #-symbol ahead of the element IDs in your $() call.

Comment: @CummanderCheckov: Oh, yeah if you already have both, then I guess it doesn't make a difference. I'll restore the original answer, and include the `#`.

Comment: Perhaps leave in your second solution as an option/additional one - for any future readers who might find it useful.

Comment: @CummanderCheckov: Yeah, I've got them both represented in the answer. :)